# How to query Date $gte in meteor on a mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-collections

I have the following objects in  a `MEC_CALENDAR_DATES` collection. My aim is to query the documents in this collection from a Meteor project greater than or equal to a start date property `Date`:

```
{
    "_id" : "vT92uJzbiDheH4FYD",
    "key" : "MEC_CALENDAR_DATES",
    "Title" : "BBS",
    "Date" : ISODate("2017-11-21T00:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "seGmNdwfQxTJnTxJz",
    "key" : "MEC_CALENDAR_DATES",
    "Title" : "AAS",
    "Date" : ISODate("2017-11-15T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

What I've tried in RoboMongo is the following query **which works** and returns the objects greater than the supplied date for that collection:

```
db.getCollection('app_configuration').find({"key":"MEC_CALENDAR_DATES", "Date": {$gte: ISODate("2017-10-03T09:35:14.561Z")}}).sort({Date: -1})
```

But when I try to translate that to Meteor using [the api](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find) zero results are returned:

```
const appConfigCollection = AppConfiguration.find({
  key: "MEC_CALENDAR_DATES",
  Date: {$gte:ISODate("2017-08-03T10:26:13.151Z")},
},
  {
    sort: {Date: -1},
});

console.log("appConfigCollection " + appConfigCollection);
```

**Question:**

How can you query documents $gte using Meteor api on a collection?

Comment: By using `new Date()` instead of `ISODate()` like every other JavaScript program. And stated so in many answers here already.

Comment: @NeilLunn ok so you mean instead of `$gte:ISODate("2017-08-03T10:26:13.151Z")` use `$gte:new Date("2017-08-03T10:26:13.151Z")`

Comment: Yep. Same goes for the shell as well. `ISODate()` is really just a "placeholder" to identify a class for the BSON Date type. It's not a special function and really just wraps `Date` in it's implementation in the shell. `Date` is the correct type for JavaScript. Just as there is a general type for just about every other language.

Comment: hmm ok in my code I'm using the var oldestDate,  getting the value using moment and converting to iso string. So maybe I should be converting to a date instead of isostring at this point?

    `const oldestDate = moment.utc().subtract(7, 'days').toISOString();`

Comment: `moment.utc().subtract(7, 'days').toDate()`. Already told you it's a `Date` object. Not an `ISODate` and not a `"string"`.

Comment: yeah makes sense that what I was getting at in my previous comment.

Comment: @BrianJ I suggest you try using the [Meteor Shell](http://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorshell) rather than the RoboMongo/Meteor Mongo, as it more closely replicates the environment your server side meteor code runs in.  You can run queries against MongoDB, though you will need to import your Collection definitions first.  e.g.  `import { AppConfiguration } from '/appconfiguration.js';  AppConfiguration.find( ... ).fetch()`